# emacs 24 auctex 11.87 no preview

Tags: latex, ubuntu-12.04, emacs24, auctex

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 with Emacs24 from the ppa:cassou/emacs repository.

This is what happens when I try to use the preview.

[image]

The message given for each image is

```
Preview-Ghostscript finished at Thu Feb  6 10:33:19
Running `Preview-Ghostscript' with ``gs -dOutputFile\=\(_region_.prv/tmp14859RfB/pr13-\%d.png\) -q -dDELAYSAFER -dNOPAUSE -DNOPLATFONTS -dPrinted -dTextAlphaBits\=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits\=4 -sDEVICE\=png16m -r88.5648x89.3216''
```

But there's no image as you can see in the picture above.

As far as I can see, the file *region*.prv/tmpXXXXXXX/preview.ps has an error, because I cannot open it. Evince tries to load it, but it stays in "loading".

Any Ideas?